# 2 questions on native tinyreq/scrapeit methods

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

The two question are on the native interface functions for the packages tinyreq/scrape-it by ionicabizau.

Let's assume we want to scrape a code like that:

```
(...)
<div class="Romania">
    <div class="Trans">a</div>
    <div class="Trans">b</div>
    <div class="Trans">c</div>
</div>
(...)
<div class="Romania">
<div class="Trans">A</div>
<div class="Trans">B</div>
<div class="Trans">C</div>
</div>
(...)
```

I'd like to know whether there is a way to select an element from a
resulting collection of the ScrapeIt function e.g. based on its index? The above
example above after parsing through:

```
scrapeIt("$url", {
    ListItem: {
        listItem: "Romania"
        , data: {
        }
        }
}, (err, data) => {
console.log(err || data);
```

gives

```
{ ListItem: [‘abc’, ‘ABC’ ] }
```

and now ... I'd like to select just the 1st or the 2nd element abve.

My second question is also simple and straightforward on how to access both resulting elements with array-like tinyreq/scrape-it native methods?

Cheers, (-)ms

Comment: Hi.
Please add the code already tried for both questions. Were happi to debug your code with you but were not here to write it for you.

Comment: Hi, let's close that since I've solved the issue base on the pure cheerio API. Though I still do not know how to do that just only with the modules tinyreq/scrape-it it is now of minor importance. @Fabian Schöner thanks for your comment ;-)